# installation error for matplotlib and Getfem to Python 3.9.0 using pip command

Tags: python, matplotlib, finite-element-analysis

**error for matplotlib:**
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lk203f52\kiwisolver\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lk203f52\kiwisolver\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-6zgl71vj'
cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lk203f52\kiwisolver
Complete output (44 lines):
WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pnxvu50s\cppy\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pnxvu50s\cppy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gic8wjko'
cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pnxvu50s\cppy
Complete output (6 lines):
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help

```
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cppy
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\dell\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmph6ki1vco', '--quiet', 'cppy>=1.1.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lk203f52\kiwisolver\setup.py", line 59, in <module>
    setup(
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 164, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 159, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 699, in fetch_build_eggs
    resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 779, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1064, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1076, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 758, in fetch_build_egg
    return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
    raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\dell\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmph6ki1vco', '--quiet', 'cppy>=1.1.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

**error for getfem:**
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement getfem (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for getfem

Can anyone suggest me how to rectify these issues?

Answer (score 1):

**sorry there is no solution because matplotlib is not supported by python 3.9 yet**

*you can solve this by degrading your python version to 3.85 or 3.5*

actually python 3.9 is new
that's why the wheel is not supported by the matplotlib